# How to process the data of MKNetworkKit on a background thread?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection

I am new with MKNetworkKit and I have a little design issue. I am trying to process the data fetched by the MKNetworkOperation on a background thread but I am not sure where to do that in order to keep the design clean.

```
[op onCompletion:^(MKNetworkOperation *completedOperation) {
    NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [completedOperation responseJSON];

    // This part is always called on the main thread but
    // I want to process here my jsonDictionary on a background thread
    // to avoid blocking the main thread
} onError:^(NSError* error) {
    errorBlock(error);
}];
```

The process time of my jsonDictionary takes a long time and I really don't want to do that on the main thread, how would you recommend me to switch to the background thread while keeping the design and philosophy of MKNetworkKit clean?

Thanks,
Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within your completion handler use this code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{

    //asynchronous code
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        //synchronous code
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure, the "asynchronous code" is on a background thread and the "synchronous code" is on the main thread?

Comment: Yes, and you can use this dispatch_async code anywhere. Not just in MKNetworkKit